# Generating Content Pages and Assigning it to a Master

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

My problem here is the following : 
i am developing a website where Lecturers are supposed to create Course Pages for every course they give in the Uni. so i don't know how i will take the values like the course name for example from the course creating page and create a content.aspx with these values which have the same layout or Design as the master page .. any suggestions ?? ( i mean in each time a Lecturer enter and create a page i want to Create a .aspx container which have the same layout as Master class )

Comment: do you want to  dynamically set the master page ?

Comment: i am a bit confused about this but let me clarify :) 
on the CourseCreatingPage say :
1) the lecturer logged in will enter in a textbox the course name that he/she want to create 
2) i want to take that name and make a new page (but of coarse the page layout will be just the same for all the course pages but with different names ) hence a master page 
3) is there any method or function that allow me to take the text the lecturer entered and create a page with that name and assign it to the master page ...

sorry if my words aren't clear enough but i am kinda new to Web Development thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not create a single page for each course, but load the content from a database. So you have a page with Querystring e.g. `~/course.aspx?courseid=123`. In `Page_Load` you can fetch the course name from the database and assign it to a `Textbox` or `Label`.

Comment: Thanks Lucky .. i don't know how this didn't come to my mind :)